# How to setup optional date field?

Tags: forms, date, symfony, doctrine-orm, admin-generator

I need to display in form optional date field with date picker.
But when I create new record it's automatically filled with current date on persist.
When I try to change it(make it blank) I've got error: "Invalid date".
I need opportunity to only optionally set this field.
It is NOT mandatory required field. Can you please tell me what am I doing wrong?

My Entity code:

```
class Entity {
...
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="date", nullable=true)
 */
private $birthday = null;
...
}
```

My generator.yml:

```
birthday:
    formType:    s2a_date_picker
```

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't use a library that tries to extend or replace legacy functionality of Symfony. It's just not worth it... the [documentation for the library](https://github.com/symfony2admingenerator/AdmingeneratorGeneratorBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/documentation.md#table-of-contents) is clear as mud too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have any validator file or rules on your entity/in your project?

Did you also tried to set the form option (via addFormOption key) 'requiered' to false?

=== Edit

I just created the following sample app:

```
generator: admingenerator.generator.doctrine
params:
    model: Application\CoreBundle\Entity\Account
    namespace_prefix: Application
    concurrency_lock: ~
    bundle_name: AdminBundle
    pk_requirement: ~
    fields:
        id:
            filterable: 1
        name:
            filterable: 1
        expirationDate:
            formType:    s2a_date_picker
    object_actions:
        delete: ~
    batch_actions:
        delete: ~
builders:
    list:
        params:
            title: List for AdminBundle
            display: ~
            filters: ~
            actions:
                new: ~
            object_actions:
                edit: ~
                delete: ~
    excel:
        params: ~
        filename: ~
        filetype: ~
    new:
        params:
            title: New object for AdminBundle
            display:
                - name
                - expirationDate
            actions:
                save: ~
                list: ~
    edit:
        params:
            title: "You're editing the object \"%object%\"|{ %object%: Account.name }|"
            display:
                - name
                - expirationDate
            actions:
                save: ~
                list: ~
    show:
        params:
            title: "You're viewing the object \"%object%\"|{ %object%: Account.name }|"
            display: ~
            actions:
                list: ~
                new: ~
    actions:
        params:
            object_actions:
                delete: ~
            batch_actions:
                delete: ~
```

With this entity mapping:

```
Application\CoreBundle\Entity\Account:
type: entity
table: null
id:
    id:
        type: integer
        id: true
        generator:
            strategy: AUTO
fields:
    name:
        type: string
        length: 255
    expirationDate:
        type: datetime
        nullable: true
lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

And of course, just in case, the entity:

```
<?php

namespace Application\CoreBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Account
 */
class Account
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     */
    private $expirationDate = null;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @return Account
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * @param \DateTime $expirationDate
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setExpirationDate(\DateTime $expirationDate = null)
    {
        $this->expirationDate = $expirationDate;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getExpirationDate()
    {
        return $this->expirationDate;
    }
}
```

And no specific customization on my entity neither my admin config or anything else... and it works well.

Does it helped you?
Are you doing something specific in your application?